# React Django CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: reactjs, django

In action file the code:

```
...
const config = {
      headers:{
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    const {data} = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/register/',
                {'email':email, 'password':password}, config)
...
```

It's working; then **localhost:8000** moved to *package.json* as a proxy, after that got an issue *CSRF token missing or incorrect*, how to fix that, thanks.
Application was restarted with no changes. Furthermore, the request has changed to *localhost:3000* instead of 8000.

Comment: Where are you sending your request from?A javascript frontend app?

Comment: Sending from react app

Answer (score 0):

Django can provide the CSRF token in your cookies with a decorator. Then you can get it from your cookies and add it as a HTTP header:

###### views.py:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie


# add this decorator to your main view 
# (the one which serves your first html/javascript code, not the /api/register one)
@ensure_csrf_cookie 
def index(request):
    ...
```

###### javascript:

```
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
...

const config = {
      headers:{
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': getCookie("csrftoken") // added the csrf cookie header
      }
    }
    const {data} = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/register/',
                {'email':email, 'password':password}, config)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what means *main view*, there is *register view*, *login view*, etc...

Comment: The first view that your user interacts with. The one which is used to "serve" the react code to your user. So you can know for sure that the cookie has been set.